# Setting an enum set based on a long value

Tags: java, enumeration

I have an enumeration that I am trying to initialize from a long value that comes from the database.

```
public enum ArticlePermission {
   NONE(0),
   CAN_READ(2),
   CAN_EDIT(4),
   CAN_DELETE(8),
   CAN_CREATE(16);

   private long _value;

   public ArticlePermission(int val) {
     this._value = val;
   }


   public long getValue() {
     return this._value;
   }


   public EnumSet<ArticlePermission> init(long val) {
     EnumSet<ArticlePermission> es = EnumSet.of(ArticlePermission.NONE);

     for(ArticlePermission p : values()) {
        if(val & p.getValue() != 0) {
          es.add(p);
        }
     }



      return es;
   }

}
```

I'm getting a compile error saying the & operator cannot be used on a long value.

How can I do this correctly then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or if you really did want to do a bitwise comparison, you just need extra parentheses:

```
if((val & getValue()) != 0) {
   // do something
   }
```

Comment: Error should be something like `operator & cannot be applied to long,boolean`. Precedence is presumably much the same for `&` as `&&` (I can't, and don't like to, remember) precedence for odd combinations. Read as `&&`, the problem is relatively obvious.

Comment: and that's because of operator precedence, != being higher than bitwise &, so you had long!=0 evaluated first to boolean and than this being &-ed with val which is illegal

Comment: Precedence of & is much higher than &&; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: @DNA I wouldn't call that much higher. (And the labelling on that table looks wrong. Surely `&` works logically as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to use `&&` (logical AND)  instead of `&` (bitwise AND) ? For if conditions you want to use the logical AND (&&).

```
if(val!=0 && p!=null && p.getValue() != 0) {
          es.add(p);
}
```

For bitwise `&` you need to use it this way:-

```
if((val & p.getValue()) != 0)) {
              es.add(p);
}
```

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - I think you are incorrect on your statement on the compilation issue. I re-tried both of the code snippets I gave and they compile fine. I am not sure where you saw the compilation issue. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: do I need to be checking for `!= 0` or `== 1`?  if I am anding, and the bits match, it should be 1, else 0 no?

Comment: @Blankman - bitwise & returns 1 if both bits are 1 and it returns 0 if any of the bits is 0. So for example if val is 3 and p.getValue() is 5 then the bitwise AND (3&5=1) will be equal to 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: @CoolBeans Must have misread it. It's still barking up the wrong tree.  / And what's with the testing against `null`?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - testing against NULL is just habit thing for me. I do that consistently to make myself avoid NPEs. But I want to understand what part is not compiling for you?

Comment: @Blankman - you must use !=0 as bitwise is **as name says** bit comparison. So you have 0 if your value does not matches and any of 1,2,4 etc. if it matches. In C-ish, you could skip !=0 altogether, but Java will not let you

Comment: @CoolBeans That's a bad practice, IMO. If the value is `null` and it shouldn't be, then there really should be an NPE **as soon as possible**. Adding `null` comparisons everywhere also unnecessarily complicates code. `null` by itself doesn't convey meaning (and even in the Java library can represent opposite meanings) - much better to disallow it.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - I agree. But sometimes you do not have control over the arguments that are being passed to your method (external apps passing it). In those cases I check for null and throw some meaningful exception back (ie. IllegalArgument). In this case for brevity sake I left that part. I will take part off and leave it as a comment for the OP to ensure that he does argument validation in the method.

Comment: @CoolBeans while 3&5 indeed is 1, but that particular example may be bit misleading to the OP - as it does not show that the result may be arbitrary number (so ==1 is invalid). Having said so, it's late and I myself made an error ORing those numbers instead of ANDing just a second ago...

Comment: @wmz I will never have 3 and 5, I am using numbers like: 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ...

Comment: @Blankman - wmz mentioned a good point. My example of 3&5 was not a good example since it results in 1. You have bitwise AND 34&11 it would be 2. So that's why you can't check for `==1`.

Comment: @Blankman - yes I know but I was referring to values used by CoolBeans. Look at my first comment please. In your particular case anding those values will yield either 0 (no match) or the p.getValue() - 1,2,4,8, .. (if matched).